# Cut out a piece from an existing image

Tags: php, image

i want to cut out a piece from an existing image and save it as an new image.

```
$src = imageCreateFromJpeg('http://domain.com/src_test_cut.jpg');
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 42, 52, 357, 200);
```

but what i don't understand .. where did the script save the new image?

Can somebody help me please

Comment: So far it saves it into memory until you output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not saved the new image yet. If you want to output it to a local file you have to call [a save function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php). For instace for a `png`:

```
imagepng($dest, "filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

In memory or temporary cache files.  Until it saved or output to the browser. please look at: [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)